Unity-Shader Graph/// i am trying hlsl to shader graph
First. Here is HLSL code
Shader "TNTC/TexturePainter"{   

    Properties{
        _PainterColor ("Painter Color", Color) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    SubShader{
        Cull Off ZWrite Off ZTest Off

        Pass{
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            
            float3 _PainterPosition;
            float _Radius;
            float _Hardness;
            float _Strength;
            float4 _PainterColor;
            float _PrepareUV;

            struct appdata{
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f{
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION; //최종적으로 화면에 렌더링될 위치
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 worldPos : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            float mask(float3 position, float3 center, float radius, float hardness){
                float m = distance(center, position);
                return 1 - smoothstep(radius * hardness, radius, m);    
            }

            v2f vert (appdata v){
                v2f o;
                o.worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                float4 uv = float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
                uv.xy = float2(1, _ProjectionParams.x) * (v.uv.xy * float2( 2, 2) - float2(1, 1));
                o.vertex = uv; 
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target{   
                if(_PrepareUV > 0 ){
                    return float4(0, 0, 1, 1);
                }         

                float4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                float f = mask(i.worldPos, _PainterPosition, _Radius, _Hardness);
                float edge = f * _Strength;
                return lerp(col, _PainterColor, edge);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}

Seconde. I am trying to same thing in unity shader graph. but, it doesn't work..


Third. how this shader is used
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using static UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventTrigger;

public class Land : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CommandBuffer cb;
    private Renderer render;

    public Shader paint;
    Material paintMaterial;

    const int TEXTURESIZE = 1024;
    RenderTexture maskRenderTexture;
    RenderTexture supportTexture;
    RenderTexture extendIslandsRenderTexture;

    int maskTextureID = Shader.PropertyToID("_MaskTexture");
    int positionID = Shader.PropertyToID("_PainterPosition");
    int radiusID = Shader.PropertyToID("_Radius");
    int colorID = Shader.PropertyToID("_PainterColor");
    int textureID = Shader.PropertyToID("_MainTex");

    int hardnessID = Shader.PropertyToID("_Hardness");
    int strengthID = Shader.PropertyToID("_Strength");

    void Start()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        cb = new CommandBuffer();

        paintMaterial = new Material(paint);

        render = GetComponent<Renderer>();

        extendIslandsRenderTexture = new RenderTexture(TEXTURESIZE, TEXTURESIZE, 0);
        extendIslandsRenderTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;

        maskRenderTexture = new RenderTexture(TEXTURESIZE, TEXTURESIZE, 0);
        maskRenderTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;

        supportTexture = new RenderTexture(TEXTURESIZE, TEXTURESIZE, 0);
        supportTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;

        render.material.SetTexture(maskTextureID, extendIslandsRenderTexture);

        Graphics.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cb);
        cb.Clear();
    }

    public void Paint(Vector2 centerPos, float radius, Color color, float hardness = 0.1f, float strength = 1f)
    {
        paintMaterial.SetFloat(hardnessID, hardness);
        paintMaterial.SetFloat(strengthID, strength);

        paintMaterial.SetVector(positionID, centerPos);
        paintMaterial.SetFloat(radiusID, radius);
        paintMaterial.SetColor(colorID, color);
        paintMaterial.SetTexture(textureID, supportTexture);

        cb.SetRenderTarget(maskRenderTexture);
        cb.DrawRenderer(render, paintMaterial, 0);

        cb.SetRenderTarget(supportTexture);
        cb.Blit(maskRenderTexture, supportTexture);

        cb.SetRenderTarget(extendIslandsRenderTexture);
        cb.Blit(maskRenderTexture, extendIslandsRenderTexture);

        Graphics.ExecuteCommandBuffer(cb);
        cb.Clear();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath + "/@Resources", "ExtendIslandsRenderTexture.png");
        SaveTextureAsPNG(extendIslandsRenderTexture, path);

        maskRenderTexture.Release();
        extendIslandsRenderTexture.Release();
        supportTexture.Release();


    }

    void SaveTextureAsPNG(RenderTexture renderTexture, string filePath)
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false); RenderTexture.active = renderTexture; texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height), 0, 0);
        texture.Apply();
        RenderTexture.active = null;

        byte[] bytes = texture.EncodeToPNG();
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
        Debug.Log("Texture saved to: " + filePath);
    }


}



Commandbuffer : DrawRenderer
PaintMaterial            ----------> MaskTexture
MainTex : supportTexture
Shader : TexturePainter

So, Shader is not targeting screen, but MaskTexture.
HLSL works fine.
Unity Shader graph not working. Did I miss something..?
I think that the problem is something about target coordinate...
so confusing
